# SQL: Can or should correlated subqueries be used with all the subquery operators?

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated

I am doing an SQL course and my teacher does not seem to have very clear if you can or should use correlated subqueries with the subquery operators like EXISTS, ALL, ANY, SOME, IN, etc... Or natural subqueries.

So in short can you use correlated subqueries with all of them or not or are you obligated to use it in some of them.

Btw I checked in W3S and Wikipedia and although they talk about correlated subqueries they don't say if there is any rule regarding the operators mentioned above.

Comment: No rules, just common sense.

Comment: Thanks, because I asked my teacher the question 3 times and she wasn't able to give me a clear answer.